# Prolog Solution to N Queens problem checking diagonal

Tags: prolog, n-queens

Disclaimer: The matrix is represented as a list where the number is the row and the index (1 - 8) is the column number.

I am new to Prolog and trying to figure out a solution to the following problem given the following guidelines:

[image: Guidelines]

My Code:

```
    eightQueens(Board) :-
        permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Board),
        checkDiagonals(Board).

    /* Check Diagonal and AntiDiagonal (Diagonal not implemented yet) 
        checkD checks antidiagonal */
    checkDiagonals([H|T]) :-
        checkD([H|T]).

    /* Value is the index of H so it acts as the column value.
       dValue is the sum of H, which represents row value, and Value.
       If any two queens have the same dValue this means they are in 
       the same anti-diagonal.
       checkD gets the dValue of the first element in the list and 
       passes it to checkDHelper which compares the dValue against 
       the dValue's of the other elements in the list. */
    checkD([]).
    checkD([H|T]) :-
        indexOf([H|T], H, RowValue),
        findValue(RowValue, H, DValue),
        checkDHelper(T, DValue),
        checkD(T).

    /* checkDHelper compares the dValue against 
       the dValue's of the other elements in the list. */ 

    checkDHelper([], DValue). 
    checkDHelper([H|T], DValue) :-
        indexOf([H|T], H, RowValueIndex),
        findValue(IndexValue, H, DValueIndex),
        %check if dValue of current index is equal to Value provided
        notEqual(DValue, DValueIndex),
        checkDHelper(T, DValue).

     %Finds index of the element
    indexOf([Element|_], Element, 1).
    indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Value) :-
         indexOf(Tail, Element, Value1),
         Value is Value1 + 1.

    %Checks if values are not equal 
    notEqual(X, Y) :-
        X =\= Y.

    %Finds dValue
    findValue(RowValue, ColumnValue, dValue) :-
        dValue is X + Y.
```

Here is an example of a board that would would work (represented as checkDiagonals([5,1,8,4,2,7,3,6]).)

[image]

Comment: Prolog does not have `functions` as in `checkD` function. Prolog is not a procedural or functional language but is a Logic 
 language and has predicates.

Comment: I can not believe the person who wrote this Prolog description used the word `function` in the problem description. Where did you get this?

Comment: For your `diagonal` predicate you need both the `Row` and `Col` positions to check it. For the `anti-diagonal` have you tried using `N+1-Row` and `Col`?

Comment: For antidiagonal you could also reverse the matrix (exchange rows with columns) and then check the diagonals with the predicate you wrote... It's sower but it works

Comment: @damianodamiano The checking the diagonal functions doesnt seem to work. Any Idea where I went wrong?

Comment: @GuyCoder The matrix is represented as a list where the number is the row and the index (1 - 8) is the column number. Also, sorry for the abuse of terminology. I should have said predicate. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: @GuyCoder First off, thanks a lot for your help! For some reason, I think my checkD predicate is not working because whenever I run it with checkDiagonals([5,1,8,4,2,7,3,6]) which should be a good board, I get false. I understand your comments in regards to the antidiagonal, I just want to make sure I have the diagonal right first.

Comment: Is this the [course](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/misc/outlines/2018/2018-cs2209-a.pdf) you are taking?

Comment: @GuyCoder The overall logic of the program is intact. All I did was add a findValue predicate that takes the row value (Number Value) and the column value (List Index) and equates it to the third argument of the predicate dValue. This dValue is then compared against other Queens to verify that no two queen's row and column values add to the same number. I will add this explanation in the initial question as well. Sorry I am new to SO.

Comment: Also you will notice that I delete my comments that I know you have read and are of not value to others. You should do the same.

Comment: @GuyCoder I changed the occurrences of dvalue with DValue and it still is returning false with the input checkDiagonals([5,1,8,4,2,7,3,6]). I have never been so frustrated programming in my life hahahah I really hate Prolog. Honestly, I can't ask anything more of you, you've been a great help, I am just going to take the loss on this assignment. I will try adding base bases first but then I am done with this hahahah

Comment: @GuyCoder Yeah, you are right. I have good grasp of logic but I clearly need to learn Prolog better. The professor left it up to us to learn the language and I have been having trouble finding tutorials on youtube or books to teach me the basics. Do you have any suggestions as to where I can get up to speed with SWI-Prolog relatively quickly?

Comment: Of interest: [Eight queens problem](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/p90.pl)

Comment: @GuyCoder I can't seem to open that file due to: Foreign predicate system:ground/1 did not clear exception: error(existence_error(procedure,prolog:file_open_event/1),context(system: $c_call_prolog/0,_72))

Comment: @GuyCoder I added detailed comments explaining the program and an example of a board that would work. Can you take a look at it quickly to see if the issue is more apparent now? The project is due tonight but is only worth a small percentage so I am not concerned about my mark. It is just killing me not being able to figure it out hahahaha

Comment: @GuyCoder Ohhh i see, this definitely a viable solution to the problem but not according to the criteria of the assignment. We are required to use the specified format in the instructions

Comment: @GuyCode Yeah I just removed that one as I was able to figure it out. This one has just stumped me lol. Hopefully someone else in the future will be able to help me out with this one but it doesnt seem like Prolog is a popular language whatsoever so I may have to face the reality that this will forever be a mystery hahahahha

Comment: @GuyCoder I really appreciate all your help today, I would never have expected to get this much assistance from one person. I am curious how you would go about it. I am not used design patterns whatsoever in logical programming. If my logic does not make sense to you, feel free to just post how you would do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is from `Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence` Fourth Edition by Ivan Bratko  ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/722841722))

page 111 - Figure 4.12 Program 2 for the eight-queens problem.

```
solution(Queens) :-
    permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Queens),
    safe(Queens).

% safe(Queens): Queens is a list of Y-coordinates of non-attacking queens

safe([]).

safe([Queen|Others]) :-
    safe(Others),
    noattack(Queen,Others,1).

% noattack(Queen, Queens, Dist):
%   Queen does not attack any queen in Queens at horizontal distance Dist

noattack(_,[],_).
noattack(Y,[Y1|Ylist],Xdist) :-
    Y1 - Y =\= Xdist,            % Not upward diagonal attack
    Y - Y1 =\= Xdist,            % Not downward diagonal attack
    Dist1 is Xdist + 1,
    noattack(Y,Ylist,Dist1).
```

Example run.

```
solution(Queens).
Queens = [1, 5, 8, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4] ;
Queens = [1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 2, 5] ;
Queens = [1, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5, 3] ;
Queens = [1, 7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3] ;
Queens = [2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 1, 7, 5] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 7, 1, 3, 8, 6, 4] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 7, 4, 1, 8, 6, 3] ;
Queens = [2, 6, 1, 7, 4, 8, 3, 5] ;
Queens = [2, 6, 8, 3, 1, 4, 7, 5] ;
Queens = [2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 5, 1, 4] ;
Queens = [2, 7, 5, 8, 1, 4, 6, 3] ;
Queens = [2, 8, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4] ;
Queens = [3, 1, 7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 2, 8, 1, 7, 4, 6] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 2, 8, 6, 4, 7, 1] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 6] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 6] ;
Queens = [3, 6, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7, 4] 
Action (h for help) ? abort
```

While this code may not look the same as yours, if you know how to [refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) Prolog code, and then change the predicate names and variable names, and rotate the board so that rows are columns and columns are rows, you will see that this answer is the same as your idea and code.

Here is the second part of the answer.

```
solution_2(N,Queens) :-
    numlist(1,N,List),
    permutation(List, Queens),
    safe(Queens).
```

Example runs.

```
?- solution_2(1,Queens).
Queens = [1] ;
false.

?- solution_2(2,Queens).
false.

?- solution_2(3,Queens).
false.

?- solution_2(4,Queens).
Queens = [2, 4, 1, 3] ;
Queens = [3, 1, 4, 2] ;
false.

?- solution_2(5,Queens).
Queens = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4] ;
Queens = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3] ;
Queens = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4] ;
Queens = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 2, 4, 1] ;
Queens = [4, 1, 3, 5, 2] ;
Queens = [4, 2, 5, 3, 1] ;
Queens = [5, 2, 4, 1, 3] ;
Queens = [5, 3, 1, 4, 2] ;
false.

?- solution_2(6,Queens).
Queens = [2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5] ;
Queens = [3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4] ;
Queens = [4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3] ;
Queens = [5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2] ;
false.

?- solution_2(7,Queens).
Queens = [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6] ;
Queens = [1, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5] ;
Queens = [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4] ;
Queens = [1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3] ;
Queens = [2, 4, 1, 7, 5, 3, 6] ;
Queens = [2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 3, 6] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 6] ;
Queens = [2, 5, 7, 4, 1, 3, 6] ;
Queens = [2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 5] ;
Queens = [2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4] ;
Queens = [3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7, 4] ;
Queens = [3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 5] ;
Queens = [3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1] ;
Queens = [3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7] ;
Queens = [3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 5] ;
Queens = [3, 7, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6] ;
Queens = [4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5] ;
Queens = [4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7] ;
Queens = [4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1, 6] ;
Queens = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2] ;
Queens = [4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1] ;
Queens = [4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3] ;
Queens = [5, 1, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2] ;
Queens = [5, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 3] ;
Queens = [5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 1] ;
Queens = [5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7] ;
Queens = [5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3] ;
Queens = [5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4] ;
Queens = [6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4] ;
Queens = [6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 3] ;
Queens = [6, 3, 1, 4, 7, 5, 2] ;
Queens = [6, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2] ;
Queens = [6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 5, 2] ;
Queens = [6, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 1] ;
Queens = [6, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2] ;
Queens = [7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5] ;
Queens = [7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4] ;
Queens = [7, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3] ;
Queens = [7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2] ;
false.
```

EDIT

From comment `The logic Bratko is using does not make sense to me.`

Try doing this if the code does not make sense. Covert a call to a predicate into write statements to see what values Prolog is feeding to the predicate. Then it sometimes makes sense and is smaller and faster than using trace at times.

```
solution_3(N,Queens) :-
    numlist(1,N,List),
    permutation(List, Queens),
    safe_3(Queens).

safe_3([]).

safe_3([Queen|Others]) :-
    safe_3(Others),
    noattack_3(Queen,Others,1).

noattack_3(_,[],_).
noattack_3(Y,[Y1|Ylist],Xdist) :-
    write('noattack_3 - Y:'),write(Y),write(', Y1: '),write(Y1),write(', Ylist: '),write(Ylist),write(', Xdist: '),writeln(Xdist),
    Dist1 is Xdist + 1,
    noattack_3(Y,Ylist,Dist1).
```

Running for a board of 3x3 gives:

```
?- solution_3(3,Queens).
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 3, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 2, Ylist: [3], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 3, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [1, 2, 3] ;
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 2, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 3, Ylist: [2], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 2, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [1, 3, 2] ;
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 3, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 1, Ylist: [3], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 3, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [2, 1, 3] ;
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 1, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 3, Ylist: [1], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 1, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [2, 3, 1] ;
noattack_3 - Y:1, Y1: 2, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 1, Ylist: [2], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 2, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [3, 1, 2] ;
noattack_3 - Y:2, Y1: 1, Ylist: [], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 2, Ylist: [1], Xdist: 1
noattack_3 - Y:3, Y1: 1, Ylist: [], Xdist: 2
Queens = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

Note that with the constraints removed it is not generating valid solutions but it is showing the generation of the values for the executions of the predicate which is what I wanted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184784/discussion-on-answer-by-guy-coder-prolog-solution-to-n-queens-problem-checking-d).